# Is there any way to check the battery percentage of Apple wireless peripherals?

Tags: bluetooth, battery, apple

I have an Apple Wireless Keyboard and a Magic Trackpad, and I was wondering if there is a way to monitor the battery life remaining/percentage like there is in OSX.

Answer (score 19):

There isn't a GUI for read wireless mouse or keyboard battery data.

You can find useful information on sysfs under `/sys/class/power_supply/`. For example the Apple Wireless Keyboard is under `/sys/class/power_supply/hid-78:CA:39:4E:6F:C7-battery/`. In the device directory there is a file named `capacity`, this is a **capacity in percents**.

So in summary, for reading Apple Wireless Keyboard battery capacity you should do:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/hid-78:CA:39:4E:6F:C7-battery/capacity
```

**Note** that `hid-78:CA:39:4E:6F:C7-battery` can be different for your device.

Comment: Huh, this is a really cool directory I never knew about! Thanks!

Comment: My device does not show in power_supply/ what to do?

Answer (score 9):

In newer Ubuntu (starting from 16.04, I guess), check under Settings -> Power

Here's a screenshot for Ubuntu 16.04 [image] .

Comment: Could you be specific about the first version you saw this on?

Comment: @MarkStosberg updated answer

Comment: Sadly on 18.04 AirPods do not show here.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article on webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/unified-messaging-menu-memenu-lands-in.html), this functionality is planned for Ubuntu 11.10 as part of Ubuntu's new Power Indicator.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your magic keyboard on Linux (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04), In settings, Select `Power Statistics` and look for keyboard

[image: Below is the screenshot]